# React-NativeCalendar Agenda doesnt have testID for Detox

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, detox, react-native-calendars

I am using detox for my react-native project and it has a calendar component using the Agenda component from react-native-calendar. I am looking to add a testID for the agenda component but there doesn't seem to be one. 
This is my agenda code.

```
  <Agenda
    items={this.state.items}
    onDayPress={(day)=>{console.log('day pressed',day)}}
    onDayChange={(day)=>{console.log('day changed')}}
    pastScrollRange={50}
    futureScrollRange={50}
    renderItem={(item, firstItemInDay) => {return (<CalendarEvent EventID={item.EventID} navigation ={this.props.navigation}/>);}}


    renderEmptyDate={() => {return (<EmptyEvent/>);}}
    // specify what should be rendered instead of ActivityIndicator
    //renderEmptyData = {() => {return (<EmptyEvent/>)}}
    rowHasChanged={(r1, r2) => {return r1.text !== r2.text}}
    // By default, agenda dates are marked if they have at least one item, but you can override this if needed
    markedDates={markedDates}
    theme={{
                    backgroundColor: '#203546',
                    calendarBackground: '#203546',
                    textSectionTitleColor: '#ffffff',
                    selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#203546',
                    selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
                    todayTextColor: '#00adf5',
                    dayTextColor: '#ffffff',
                    textDisabledColor: '#ffffff',
                    dotColor: '#ffffff',
                    selectedDotColor: '#ffffff',
                    monthTextColor: '#ffffff',
                    textMonthFontWeight: 'bold',
                    textDayFontSize: 16,
                    textMonthFontSize: 20,
                    textDayHeaderFontSize: 15,
                    agendaDayTextColor: 'white',
                    agendaDayNumColor: 'white',
                    agendaTodayColor: '#00adf5',
                    agendaKnobColor: 'white'
                    }}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick [search](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/search?q=testID&unscoped_q=testID) of the `react-native-calendars` repo shows that the `testID` prop is only supported in the `CalendarHeader` component.

It appears the remaining components provided by that library don't support `testID` but that doesn't mean they cannot.

If you look at the Detox [troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#cant-find-my-component-even-though-i-added-testid-to-its-props) for adding a `testID` prop is states:

> **Solution**: React Native only supports the `testID` prop on the native
>   built-in components. If you've created a custom composite component,
>   you will have to support this prop yourself. You should probably
>   propagate the testID prop to one of your rendered children (a built-in
>   component):

Unfortunately the `Agenda` component is not one that you created yourself so there isn't much control you can have over its props. There are a few courses of action that you could take:

1. Create an issue, and hope that someone on the repo's dev team makes the change you want.
2. Fork the library. This will now give you complete control over the component. You will be able to add the `testID` props that you require. You can then use your forked version of the library. This may be useful but note that you will have to maintain the forked repo. You could always submit the change as a PR and it might get merged into an actual release.

The fastest solution is obviously option 2. You could then use your forked version in your `package.json` as follows:

```
"react-native-calendars": "your_github_name/react-native-calendars"
```